# Deleting Data from a file in Java

Tags: java

I am having an issue with deleting an old line of text and replacing it with a new line of text. Then ultimately storing it in a text file. Instead of deleting the old line, the new line is written together with the old text, which defeats the purpose of the function. For example if my data.txt file contains " i am a poet" and I want to replace this sentence with " i am actually a philosopher". The first is concatenated with the latter instead of being removed.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
 public static void removedata(String s) throws IOException {

    File f = new File("data.txt");
    File f1 = new File("data2.txt");
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            System.in));
    // String s = "test";
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(f1);
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contains(s)) {
            System.out.println(line + " is found already");

            System.out.println("would you like to rewrite new data?");
            String go = input.readLine();
            if (go.equals("yes")) {
                System.out.println("Enter new Text :");
                String newText = input.readLine();
                line = line.replace(s, newText);
            }
        }

        pr.println(line);
    }
    br.close();
    pr.close();
    input.close();
    Files.move(f1.toPath(), f.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

}
```

Comment: This seems to work as I'd expect when I run it. Instances of the matched String `s` are replaced with the specified replacement, non matching Strings are left untouched. Can you explain clearly what you were expecting to see (with a before/after example)?

Comment: I was expecting to see "I am here" found and replaced with "she is here" in the text file. But instead the text file contains " she is here I am here". I do not want to see any old instances of the sentence in the text file.

Comment: hm, I'm definitely seeing the behavior you're expecting when I run your code. I'm calling the method `removedata("I am");` and the replacement occurs correctly, though I see odd behavior if I call it with an empty String argument. Could you update your code to be a [minimum complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so I can try to replicate what you are seeing?

Comment: Set some string to "I am" then pass that String as an argument for removedata. Eg String blank = "i am" and removedata(blank), From there you could see where my issue is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is getting a little big for a comment.

If I start with a data.txt of `i am a poet` and call `removedata("i am");` then run the program and enter `she is` as the new Text, then the final data.txt is `she is a poet`. This is working as designed - only the segment `i am` is replaced with `she is` because this is how the [String.replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) works. The only way to get the behavior you are describing is to enter `i am actually a philosopher` as the new Text, which will instead result in a final data.txt of `i am actually a philosopher a poet`. If you want to replace the whole line with the user specified new Text, simply change the line:

```
line = line.replace(s, newText);
```

to:

```
line = newText;
```

Otherwise, this appears to be working as intended.